# insert an image from the internet in R

Tags: r, image

I would like to insert an image from the internet, this is my code, but it marks an error, I have already read the manual and I have looked for ways but I cannot find how

```
myft <- flextable( head(iris))
abajo<-"https://github.com/Temisesba/P-blico/raw/main/arriba.png"
myft <- compose( myft, i = 1:3, j = 1,
                 value = as_paragraph(
                   as_image(src = abajo, width = .20, height = .15),
                   " blah blah ",
                   as_chunk(Sepal.Length)),
                 part = "body")
myft
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could download the file and insert it

```
library(flextable)
download.file("https://github.com/Temisesba/P-blico/raw/main/arriba.png", "arriba.png")

myft <- compose( myft, i = 1:3, j = 1,
                 value = as_paragraph(
                   as_image(src = "arriba.png", width = .20, height = .15),
                   " blah blah ",
                   as_chunk(Sepal.Length)),
                 part = "body")
myft
```

-output

[image]

Comment: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68614353/7223434) is a new question you might like.