# lopping over the input value of an tidyverse/rlang-based function

Tags: r, dataframe, function, loops, tidyverse

My function `foo` works great for *one input value* for its `cat_mod` argument. But I wonder how to make it accept more than one input for `cat_mod` given the use of `rlang::ensym(cat_mod)` in my function?

```
foo <- function(data, study_id, cat_mod){
  
  study_id <- rlang::ensym(study_id)
  cat_mod <- rlang::ensym(cat_mod)
  
  studies_cats <- 
    data %>%
    dplyr::group_by(!!study_id, !!cat_mod) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(effects = n())
  
  cat_names <- paste0(rlang::as_string(cat_mod), c(".x", ".y"))
  
  studies_cats <- 
    studies_cats %>%
    dplyr::inner_join(studies_cats, by = rlang::as_string(study_id)) %>%
    dplyr::group_by(!!!rlang::syms(cat_names)) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(
      studies = n(),
      effects = sum(effects.x)) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(n = paste0(studies, " (", effects, ")") )
  
  studies_cats %>%
    dplyr::select(-studies, -effects) %>%
    tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = cat_names[2], values_from = n) %>%
    dplyr::rename(`Moderator Category` = cat_names[1])
}  

#===

## Example of use when using a single input for `cat_mod`:

data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m2/main/q.csv")

foo(data, study.name, time_wk)

foo(data, study.name, treats)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we want to use the same function, then use `map` by looping over a character string

```
library(purrr)
map(c('time_wk', 'treats'),  ~foo(data, study.name, !!.x))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 12 x 13
# Groups:   Moderator Category [12]
   `Moderator Category` `0`     `2`     `4`     `6`    `7`   `8`    `9`    `12`   `24`  `40`   `1`     `3`   
                  <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr> 
 1                    0 22 (86) 5 (16)  8 (27)  3 (10) 1 (4) 2 (7)  2 (10) 1 (6)  1 (4) 2 (16) <NA>    <NA>  
 2                    1 <NA>    1 (12)  6 (35)  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   19 (95) 2 (6) 
 3                    2 5 (16)  11 (60) <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   1 (12)  <NA>  
 4                    3 <NA>    <NA>    1 (4)   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   2 (6)   4 (11)
 5                    4 8 (27)  <NA>    15 (71) <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   1 (6)  <NA>  <NA>   6 (35)  1 (4) 
 6                    6 3 (10)  <NA>    <NA>    3 (10) <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   1 (4) 1 (4)  <NA>    <NA>  
 7                    7 1 (4)   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   1 (4) <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>    <NA>  
 8                    8 2 (7)   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  3 (13) <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>    <NA>  
 9                    9 2 (10)  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   2 (10) <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>    <NA>  
10                   12 1 (6)   <NA>    1 (6)   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   2 (10) <NA>  <NA>   <NA>    <NA>  
11                   24 1 (4)   <NA>    <NA>    1 (4)  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   1 (4) 1 (4)  <NA>    <NA>  
12                   40 2 (16)  <NA>    <NA>    1 (4)  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   1 (4) 2 (16) <NA>    <NA>  

[[2]]
# A tibble: 12 x 13
# Groups:   Moderator Category [12]
   `Moderator Category` `1`      `2`      `3`     `4`   `5`    `7`    `8`   `9`   `12`   `14`  `35`  `NA`  
                  <int> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> 
 1                    1 13 (121) <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 2                    2 <NA>     14 (114) <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 3                    3 <NA>     <NA>     10 (50) <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 4                    4 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    2 (9) <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 5                    5 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  3 (31) <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 6                    7 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   2 (20) <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 7                    8 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   1 (2) <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 8                    9 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  1 (2) <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 9                   12 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  1 (24) <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
10                   14 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   1 (4) <NA>  <NA>  
11                   35 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  1 (2) <NA>  
12                   NA <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  2 (11)
```

---

The function can be changed to add 3 dots (`...`) for multiple parameters to be passed

```
foo <- function(data, study_id, ...){
  
   study_id <- rlang::ensym(study_id)
   cat_mod <- rlang::ensyms(...)
   purrr::map(cat_mod,  ~ {
  
   studies_cats <- 
     data %>%
     dplyr::group_by(!!study_id, !!.x) %>%
     dplyr::summarise(effects = n(), .groups = 'drop')
     nm1 <- rlang::as_string(.x)
     cat_names <- paste0(nm1, c(".x", ".y"))
    studies_cats <- 
      studies_cats %>%
      dplyr::inner_join(studies_cats, by = rlang::as_string(study_id)) %>%
      dplyr::group_by(!!!rlang::syms(cat_names)) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(
        studies = n(),
        effects = sum(effects.x), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(n = paste0(studies, " (", effects, ")") )

    studies_cats %>%
      dplyr::select(-studies, -effects) %>%
      tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = cat_names[2], values_from = n) %>%
      dplyr::rename_with(~nm1,  cat_names[1])     
 
    }  
    )
 }
```

-testing

```
foo(data, study.name,time_wk, treats )
[[1]]
# A tibble: 12 x 13
   time_wk `0`     `2`     `4`     `6`    `7`   `8`    `9`    `12`   `24`  `40`   `1`     `3`   
     <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr> 
 1       0 22 (86) 5 (16)  8 (27)  3 (10) 1 (4) 2 (7)  2 (10) 1 (6)  1 (4) 2 (16) <NA>    <NA>  
 2       1 <NA>    1 (12)  6 (35)  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   19 (95) 2 (6) 
 3       2 5 (16)  11 (60) <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   1 (12)  <NA>  
 4       3 <NA>    <NA>    1 (4)   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   2 (6)   4 (11)
 5       4 8 (27)  <NA>    15 (71) <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   1 (6)  <NA>  <NA>   6 (35)  1 (4) 
 6       6 3 (10)  <NA>    <NA>    3 (10) <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   1 (4) 1 (4)  <NA>    <NA>  
 7       7 1 (4)   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   1 (4) <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>    <NA>  
 8       8 2 (7)   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  3 (13) <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>    <NA>  
 9       9 2 (10)  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   2 (10) <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>    <NA>  
10      12 1 (6)   <NA>    1 (6)   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   2 (10) <NA>  <NA>   <NA>    <NA>  
11      24 1 (4)   <NA>    <NA>    1 (4)  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   1 (4) 1 (4)  <NA>    <NA>  
12      40 2 (16)  <NA>    <NA>    1 (4)  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   1 (4) 2 (16) <NA>    <NA>  

[[2]]
# A tibble: 12 x 13
   treats `1`      `2`      `3`     `4`   `5`    `7`    `8`   `9`   `12`   `14`  `35`  `NA`  
    <int> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> 
 1      1 13 (121) <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 2      2 <NA>     14 (114) <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 3      3 <NA>     <NA>     10 (50) <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 4      4 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    2 (9) <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 5      5 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  3 (31) <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 6      7 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   2 (20) <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 7      8 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   1 (2) <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 8      9 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  1 (2) <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 9     12 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  1 (24) <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
10     14 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   1 (4) <NA>  <NA>  
11     35 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  1 (2) <NA>  
12     NA <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  2 (11)
```

---

If we want to name the list elements

```
foo <- function(data, study_id, ...){
  
   study_id <- rlang::ensym(study_id)
   cat_mod <- rlang::ensyms(...)
   cat_mod_names <- purrr::map_chr(cat_mod,  ~rlang::as_string(.x))
   purrr::imap(setNames(cat_mod, cat_mod_names),  ~ {
   nm1 <- .y
   studies_cats <- 
     data %>%
     dplyr::group_by(!!study_id, !!.x) %>%
     dplyr::summarise(effects = n(), .groups = 'drop')
     
     cat_names <- paste0(nm1, c(".x", ".y"))
    studies_cats <- 
      studies_cats %>%
      dplyr::inner_join(studies_cats, by = rlang::as_string(study_id)) %>%
      dplyr::group_by(!!!rlang::syms(cat_names)) %>%
      dplyr::summarise(
        studies = n(),
        effects = sum(effects.x), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(n = paste0(studies, " (", effects, ")") )

    studies_cats %>%
      dplyr::select(-studies, -effects) %>%
      tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = cat_names[2], values_from = n) %>%
      dplyr::rename_with(~nm1,  cat_names[1])  %>%
       dplyr::select(1, gtools::mixedorder(names(.)[-1]) + 1)       
 
    }  
    )
 }
```

-testing

```
foo(data, study.name,time_wk, treats )
$time_wk
# A tibble: 12 x 13
   time_wk `0`     `1`     `2`     `3`    `4`     `6`    `7`   `8`    `9`    `12`   `24`  `40`  
     <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr> 
 1       0 22 (86) <NA>    5 (16)  <NA>   8 (27)  3 (10) 1 (4) 2 (7)  2 (10) 1 (6)  1 (4) 2 (16)
 2       1 <NA>    19 (95) 1 (12)  2 (6)  6 (35)  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  
 3       2 5 (16)  1 (12)  11 (60) <NA>   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  
 4       3 <NA>    2 (6)   <NA>    4 (11) 1 (4)   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  
 5       4 8 (27)  6 (35)  <NA>    1 (4)  15 (71) <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   1 (6)  <NA>  <NA>  
 6       6 3 (10)  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   <NA>    3 (10) <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   1 (4) 1 (4) 
 7       7 1 (4)   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   <NA>    <NA>   1 (4) <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  
 8       8 2 (7)   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  3 (13) <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  
 9       9 2 (10)  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   2 (10) <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  
10      12 1 (6)   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   1 (6)   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   2 (10) <NA>  <NA>  
11      24 1 (4)   <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   <NA>    1 (4)  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   1 (4) 1 (4) 
12      40 2 (16)  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   <NA>    1 (4)  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   1 (4) 2 (16)

$treats
# A tibble: 12 x 13
   treats `1`      `2`      `3`     `4`   `5`    `7`    `8`   `9`   `12`   `14`  `35`  `NA`  
    <int> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> 
 1      1 13 (121) <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 2      2 <NA>     14 (114) <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 3      3 <NA>     <NA>     10 (50) <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 4      4 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    2 (9) <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 5      5 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  3 (31) <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 6      7 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   2 (20) <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 7      8 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   1 (2) <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 8      9 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  1 (2) <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
 9     12 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  1 (24) <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  
10     14 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   1 (4) <NA>  <NA>  
11     35 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  1 (2) <NA>  
12     NA <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  2 (11)
```

Comment: Hi Arun, in the `foo` function above, we added the last line of code (`dplyr::select(1, order(names(.)[-1]) + 1)`) to make sure the values of the first column are ordered like the rest of columns' names. But it seems this line has a bug. If you try: `d = read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/s/main/w7_smd_raw.csv"); foo(data, study, error.type)`, you'll see the first column's values are ordered as: `0,1,2,3,10`,  but rest of the columns' names are ordered as: `0,1,10,2,3`. Can you remove this bug?

Comment: @rnorouzian try with the update `dplyr::select(1, gtools::mixedorder(names(.)[-1]) + 1)`